# translation explanation

Tags: grammar, translation

my Japanese teacher translated this sentence 作品作ってたらこんな時間なってもた。as: "While making the work, it suddenly became so late (or something in that sense..). I would like to ask why 'while'when there is 'たら' which indicates that it is a condition. But it actually makes no sense to me if it was a conditional.thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I must mention the fact that the sentence in question is dialectal.

> 「作品作{さくひんつく}って**たら**こんな時間{じかん}（に）なっても（う）た。」

is Kansai speech for:

> 「作品作って**たら**こんな時間になってしまった。」

This 「たら」 actually is conditional in the broad sense of the word.  It is just not the ***if*** kind of conditional but is the ***when*** kind.

It is used to express the ***sequence*** of two events -- "**When A happened, B happened**."  Please note that **A represents the cause and B, the effect**.

If it were not for A, B would not happen.  It is "conditional" in that sense.

> Cause: "I was creating my work." ➡ I was really concentrating.
>
> Effect: "I never knew that it was so late." ➡ I did not even think about the time (to go home).